# Cannot install packages for Python Azure Function

Tags: python, module, azure-functions

I have a Python Azure function which executes locally. It is deployed to Azure and I selected the '**free app plan**'. The Python has dependencies on various modules, such as `requests`. The modules are not loaded into the app like they are locally on my machine. The function fails when triggered.

- I have tried installing the dependencies using **Kudu console** from my site, this hangs with message **cleaning up >>** every time.
- I have tried installing the dependencies using **SSH terminal** from my site, the installations succeed but i cannot see the modules when `python pip list` in kudo and the app still fails. I cannot navigate the directories `ls` does nothing.
- I tried to install extensions using the **portal** but this option is greyed out in development-tools.

Comment: Try to use cmd to deploy your function.

Comment: On linux azure function, we can not use Kudu to install modules. It is different from windows OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a requirements.txt in your local function folder.

If you want function on azure to install the 'requests', your requirements.txt should be like this:(Azure will install the extension based on this file)

```
azure-functions
requests
```

And all these packages will be packaged into a new package on Azure, so you can not display which packages using `pip list`. Also, please keep in mind that Linux's Kudu feature is limited and you cannot install packages through it.

Problem seems comes from VS Code, you can use command to deploy your function app.

For example, my functionapp on Azure named 423PythonBowman2, So this is my command:

```
func azure functionapp publish 423PythonBowman --build remote
```

I quoted requests in the code, and with cmd deploy my function can works fine on portal with no errors.

Have a look of the offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=macos%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#publish

Comment: I added the module names to requirements.txt, followed by pubishing the project to Azure. The same missing module error was raised. I then tried to execute the command `func 
azure functionapp publish jupiterfunction01 --build remote` which rerdeploys to an existing remote app (the functionality also exists in VSC GUI) and the console returns **Remote Build Failed!**, no other information.